# Typescript: parameter 'error' implicitly has an 'any' type

Tags: typescript

First day with typescript and i got ~logic error?

**server.ts**

```
interface StopAppCallback {
    (err: Error | null): void
}

interface StartAppCallback {
    (err: Error | null, result?: Function): void
}

export default (startCb: StartAppCallback): void => {
    const stopApp = (stopCb: StopAppCallback): void => {
        return stopCb(null)
    }

    return startCb(null, stopApp)
}
```

**boot.ts**

```
import server from './src/server'

server((err, stopApp) => { //<-- no error
    if (err) {
        throw err
    }

    if (typeof stopApp !== 'function') {
        throw new Error('required typeof function')
    }

    stopApp((error) => { //<-- tsc error
        if (error) {
            throw error
        }
    })
})
```

tsc error: **parameter 'error' implicitly has an 'any' type**

I don't get it, interfaces are defined and set in same way. So whats the deal?
Turning off *noImplicitAny* and *strict* in settings or adding *:any* is dum.

What i don't understand in tsc logic? Or i am defining something wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is with the `StartAppCallback` interface, defining `result?` as `Function`. The callback passed to `stopApp` becomes the type `Function`. Functions with that type don't have any definite type for their arguments, hence the error. A simpler example:

```
// this will give the error you're dealing with now
const thing: Function = (arg) => arg
```

Solution: define `result` as what it actually is:

```
interface StartAppCallback {
  (err: Error | null, result?: (stopCb: StopAppCallback) => void): void
}
```

As a general rule, try to avoid the `Function` type whenever possible, as it leads to unsafe code.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you didn't add the the type of the passed parameter in the
**Arrow** function.

For example:

```
let printing=(message)=>{
    console.log(message);
}
```

This will cause an error

> - error TS7006: Parameter 'message' implicitly has an 'any' type.

The correct way is:

```
let printing=(message:string )=>{
    console.log(message);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add type to your code, for example

```
server((err: String, stopApp) => { //<-- added String type
```